# Remove column rows in a table

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I developed a table using the bootstrap.
The objective was to obtain a table in which the rows have a background color and each row in the table must be separate.

My problem is that when separating the rows of the table, a spacing appears between the rows of the column.

How can I remove this blank spacing, thus filling the entire line with the background color?

[DEMO](https://www.codeply.com/p/kvoWNiqgaZ)

```css
.tableTitles {
  text-align: left;
  font-family: 'Noto Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: bold;
  letter-spacing: 0;
  color: #4D4F5C;
}

.circle {
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  line-height: 32px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #4981C226;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-family: 'Noto Sans', sans-serif;
  letter-spacing: 0;
  color: #4981C2;
}

.tableColor {
  /* background: #F4F5F7 0% 0% no-repeat padding-box; */
  border-radius: 8px;
}

.myTable {
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-spacing: 7px;
}

.tableUserPhoto {
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  transform: matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
  border-radius: 8px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<table class="card-table table-borderless myTable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col tableTitles">Title</th>
      <th scope="col tableTitles">Title1</th>
      <th scope="col tableTitles">Title2</th>
      <th scope="col tableTitles">Title3</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr style="background-color: grey">
      <td class="tableTitles">
        Title
      </td>
      <td class="tableTitles">
        Title1
      </td>
      <td class="tableTitles">
        Title2
      </td>
      <td class="tableTitles">
        Title3
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="background-color: grey">
      <td class="tableTitles">
        Title
      </td>
      <td class="tableTitles">
        Title1
      </td>
      <td class="tableTitles">
        Title2
      </td>
      <td class="tableTitles">
        Title3
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**Problem**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`border-spacing` takes two values, horizontal and vertical.

> When two  values are specified, the first value defines the horizontal spacing between cells (i.e., the space between cells in adjacent columns), and the second value defines the vertical spacing between cells (i.e., the space between cells in adjacent rows).
>
> [**MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-spacing)

---

> The objective was to obtain a table in which the rows have a background color and each row in the table must be separate.

What I *think* you want is:

```
  .myTable{
    border-collapse: separate;
    border-spacing: 0 7px;
  }
```

```css
.myTable {
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-spacing: 0 7px;
}
```

```html
<table class="card-table table-borderless myTable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col tableTitles">Title</th>
      <th scope="col tableTitles">Title1</th>
      <th scope="col tableTitles">Title2</th>
      <th scope="col tableTitles">Title3</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr style="background-color: grey">
      <td class="tableTitles">
        Title
      </td>
      <td class="tableTitles">
        Title1
      </td>
      <td class="tableTitles">
        Title2
      </td>
      <td class="tableTitles">
        Title3
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="background-color: grey">
      <td class="tableTitles">
        Title
      </td>
      <td class="tableTitles">
        Title1
      </td>
      <td class="tableTitles">
        Title2
      </td>
      <td class="tableTitles">
        Title3
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

remove **border-spacing** or set it to **0px** in myTable class

```
.myTable{
    border-collapse: separate;
    border-spacing: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Your problem is that **border-spacing** creates space to row and column if you don't specify two values (as you are doing).

So, you need to do something as the following:

```
.myTable {
    border-collapse: separate;
    border-spacing: 0px 7px;
}
```

So that table has 7px between each row and 0px between each column.